# Diferencia entre estructuras y clases en C++

Tags: c++, clase, struct

¿Que diferencia hay en C++ entre una estructura y una clase? Segun lo que yo entiendo, una estructura es la forma en c++ de crear un objeto, asi como en python se usa class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La única diferencia entre `class` y `struct` es la visibilidad de sus miembros, siendo los miembros de `struct` públicos por defecto mientras que los de `class` son privados por defecto.

Obviando esa diferencia, ambos constructos son iguales:

#### Ambos pueden usarse en herencia

```
struct A {};
class B {};

struct C : public A, public B {};
class D : public A, public B {};
```

Esto implica que también ambos pueden tener funciones virtuales, virtuales puras, sobreescribir funciones y usar cualquier nivel de herencia.

#### Ambos pueden tener miembros públicos, protegidos y privados

```
struct S
{
    int publico; // miembro publico.
protected:
    int protegido; // miembro protegido.
private:
    int privado; // miembro privado.
};
```

```
class C
{
    int privado; // miembro privado.
protected:
    int protegido; // miembro protegido.
public:
    int publico; // miembro publico.
};
```

#### Ambos auto-generan las funciones especiales

En ambos casos, si no se define explícitamente, se creará automáticamente:

- Constructor por defecto.
- Constructor de copia.
- Constructor de movimiento.
- Operador de copia-asignación.
- Destructor.

#### Ambos pueden ser pre-declarados

```
struct S; // pre-declaracion de S
class C; // pre-declaracion de C

struct S { int i; }; // declaracion de S
class C { int i; }; // declaracion de C
```

Quería mencionar este punto porque es posible pre-declarar un objeto como `class` y después declararlo como `struct` (y viceversa); la mayoría de compiladores aceptan esto aunque suelen mostrar una alarma.

#### Ambos tienen la misma estructura en memoria

Una clase y una estructura con los mismos miembros en el mismo orden, ocuparán lo mismo en memoria y tendrán los mismos [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) entre miembros.

```
struct S { char c; short s; int i; float f; double d; };
class C { char c; short s; int i; float f; double d; };

static_assert(sizeof(S) == sizeof(C)); // Verdadero!
```

Comment: Wow, son casi lo mismo solamente se diferencian en la visibilidad de los miembros, pero y las Union? son parecidas tambien o son diferentes en algo?

Comment: Entonces, ¿da igual como haga un objeto, si con struct o class? ¿Voy a obtener los mismos resultados?

Comment: @Jogofus depende de lo que entiendas por "*mismos resultados*", salvo por la visibilidad por defecto de los miembros, `struct` o `class` actúan de la misma manera.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de lo mencionado en otras respuestas sobre el tema de la visibilidad (tema sobre el que no voy a comentar porque ya está sobradamente documentado en otras respuestas) hay una segunda diferencia entre el uso de `struct` y `class` y es en el caso de `template`:

`class` se puede usar para declarar tipos para un `template`, mientras que `struct` no:

```
// ok
template<class T>
void func1(T t)
{ std::cout << t << '\n'; }

// ok
template<typename T>
void func2(T t)
{ std::cout << t << '\n'; }


// error
template<struct T>
void func3(T t)
{ std::cout << t << '\n'; }
```

Comment: No estoy seguro al 100% pero creo que se debe a diferencias semánticas de la misma palabra reservada en diferentes contextos... es decir: `class` dentro de template no significa lo mismo que `class` para declarar objetos ergo, aún siendo la misma palabra clave: no son lo mismo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Usar `class` para definir tipos en un template no implica para nada que ese tipo se deba especializar con una clase... se puede personalizar con `int` y no pasa nada. Pero no deja de ser una diferencia entre ambas palabras dentro de C++

Comment: El uso de `class` en el contexto de parámetro plantilla es por razones históricas: no se quería crear otra palabra clave (que al final se creó: `typename`). El significado de `class` dentro de la plantilla es diferente al de `class` fuera de ese contexto, así pues: son diferentes palabras clave homónimas.

Comment: @PAAperBirdMaster la pregunta  va de diferencias entre `struct` y `class`. No veo que se especifique un contexto determinado, luego no veo que la respuesta esté fuera de lugar

Comment: Asumo que la pregunta va de diferencias entre los objetos `struct` y `class`, no entre los significados de ambas palabras clave... de todas maneras no he dicho que la respuesta esté fuera de lugar si no que `class` en contexto de objeto y contexto de plantilla no son lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

En C++ `struct` y `class` son prácticamente lo mismo, con la única diferencia que en una `struct` los miembros por defecto son públicos y en una `class` por defecto son privados.

Una `struct` puede contener lo mismo que una `class`, métodos, constructores, destructores, herencia.